# Moving an object to another on a random path

Tags: java, object

I have a program which creates multiple  randomly placed objects(balls) at the beginning, now im trying to move the player ball towards the closest object automatically until their centres are the same. I have determined the distance of the closest object stored in an array called distance with index of 'closest', and set the  speed as variable delta initialised somewhere else, how do i get the direction right? Right now 
It moves just diagonally but not towards the closest ball

coordinatex[closest] and coordinatey[closest] are the x and y coordinates of the closest object.

playerObject.getX and playerObjectgetY gives me the coordinates of the player onject

```
public void move(int delta) {
     for(int i=0; i<distance[closest]; i++) {
        if (x<coordinatex[closest] && y<coordinatey[closest]) {     
            playerObject.setX(playerObject.getX() + 0.1*delta);     
            playerObject.setY(playerObject.getY() + 0.1*delta);    
        } else if(x>coordinatex[closest] && y>coordinatey[closest]) {     
            playerObject.setX(playerObject.getX() - 0.1*delta);     
            playerObject.setY(playerObject.getY() - 0.1*delta);    
        } else if(x>coordinatex[closest] && y<coordinatey[closest]) {     
            playerObject.setX(playerObject.getX() - 0.1*delta);     
            playerObject.setY(playerObject.getY() + 0.1*delta);    
        } else if (x<coordinatex[closest] && y>coordinatey[closest]) {     
            playerObject.setX(playerObject.getX() + 0.1*delta);     
            playerObject.setY(playerObject.getY() - 0.1*delta);         
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something very similar to this:

```
angle=atan2(ClosestBally-player_y,closestBallx-player_x);
dxperframe = cos(angle);
dyperframe = sin(-angle);
```

Comment: could you please explain dxperframe and dyperframe?

Answer (score 0):

I see your handlers for the four semi-cardinal (diagonal) directions, but *not* the four [cardinal directions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction). In this [game](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/), for example, enemies approach the player in a step-wise manner using the [`move(int row, int col)`](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/org/gcs/robot/RCModel.html#move%28int,%20int%29) method, shown [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/robotchase/code/67/tree/trunk/src/org/gcs/robot/RCModel.java#l238), from any of eight directions.

Comment: but my program does not have keyboard input, the object should move to the other object automatically

Comment: I presume your `move()` is invoked for each increment of simulated time. The game uses a `javax.swing.Timer`, which is enabled by default. Click on any square to see the enemies advance on the moving player.